# Is there a reason that you cannot dismiss this banner while not signed in?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

Stack Overflow shows a banner just below the menu bar encouraging users that aren't signed in to sign up.  There is a button to sign up and there is an 'x' button, which seems like it should dismiss the banner.  However, as you can see in the gif, it doesn't dismiss the banner.  I have disabled privacy badger on Stack Overflow which sometimes blocks Javascript on pages, so it doesn't appear that an extension is causing this behavior.

[image]

Comment: Weird, I can't duplicate this because that dark sign up bar won't show up for me.

Comment: Maybe there is some type of split testing going on where only certain sessions are getting it?  I can get the same type of behavior in FireFox as well.

Comment: IIRC correctly I saw another answer here or on MSE reporting the same thing but I can't find it. I did report it in chat [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7022802#7022802) so I guess Adam Lear is still looking into it

Comment: Yeah, something's screwed there (for one, that top banner shouldn't show up on SO in the first place!). I'm looking into it.

Comment: I think SO relies a little too much on live testing and bug reports by Meta users, which means many scenarios are not tested for not-logged-in users - and those are the majority of users. (here's a [recent example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311289/7586))

Comment: I see at least seven extensions with icons on your address bar; are you sure none of them (nor any others) are not affecting this, either?

Comment: FWIW when you click the cross the "home" link to the left is selected. I think if this was a bug with SO then we'd have more people moaning, and I'd be more inclined to assume it's something at your end. Something that greasemonkey etc. I'd suggest you clear all history etc and turn off all addons and see if the issue is still present

Comment: I managed to replicate this behaviour on chrome 67.0.3396.87 on Windows 10 (64-bit). After opening [so] in an incognito tab (quickest way for me to not be logged in), I opened a question, closed the cookie policy pop-up at the bottom of the screen, closed the login pop-up that appears at the bottom of the screen, then it appeared and was not closable. This was the *only* way I could make the black bar appear and after a hard refresh it wouldn't appear again.

Comment: Not sure if "I had this same problem" is a valid answer, but I did encounter this using a plain old Firefox browser, no plugins or extensions added.

Comment: @Kobi Define *"too much"*. You can't test everything for every scenario, with every browser. Resources are finite and SE sites are pretty stable sites, so I'd say the *really important* things are getting tested. Can they do better? They surely can! Who cannot? But I often read pretty harsh criticism for minor visual bugs that get resolved pretty quickly once reported. You may disagree with me, and that's fine; but I see so many negative comments in Metas that I just wanted to put my 2 cents on the other plate of the balance

Comment: @xDaizu - I agree that Meta is too negative and many new feature are accepted with downright hostility, which I consciously try to avoid, and I certainly didn't intend to be harsh. I said "*a little* too much", and I meant that IMO there could have been fewer bugs. This bug, and the one I linked, occurred in all browsers and without any extensions, and are very simple to find. Generally, I wouldn't call banners that cannot be closed minor visual bugs because many people see them as spam and get increasingly annoyed by them.

Comment: @Kobi You're right that it's an apparently easy to spot bug. Sorry, maybe there were more appropiate snarky comments to answer to than yours. It's just... reading all that negativity gets so tiresome.. -.-

Comment: There is also a banner at the bottom that makes you aware that the website uses cookies. It would also return every day if you're not registered on that particular website. And it's pretty tall.

Comment: The cookie banner returns every day whether you are registered or not.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: It doesn't for me. I think I dismissed it once, and it hasn't reappeared since. If it does for you, that sounds like a bug.

Comment: I have dismissed it seemingly every day for the last week or so.

Comment: @James I'd be more inclined to think the user's mouse was the blame. It almost looks like there's a drag event instead of a click going on.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy yep. I know why the banner is there but the cookie banner is a bit amusing if you use SO in an incognito tab, 'this site uses cookies to remember you', (next day) 'this site uses cookies to remember you', (next day) 'this site uses cookies to remember you'; "Well I guess I don't have to worry about data collection on SO."

Comment: And today it did not appear. Maybe it only appears on SE sites that I am not registered on. I do read various hot questions that catch my eye. Maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Adam fixed this Friday:

[image: animation of dismiss button working on banner displayed at bottom of page]